# I need to take the output of command and make it the name of a file using a script

Tags: shell-script, rhel, swap

I am working on a way to integrate our Linux machines into our SCCM Reports. One of the things we would like to do is verify the swap size on the machines.

I know that I can get the swap amount on the machine by running

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep SwapTotal
```

Unfortunately, SCCM can't run these commands, but our SCCM Administrator says that if I can create a file in a folder, he can read that file into the report as long as it has a special ending.

I would like to take the information from that command, and pipe it to the filename, so if the swap was 6000, the file would be named 6000.swap

Can anyone point me in the direction of where I can find how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If the only thing that matters is the resulting filename:

```
rm -f *.swap
touch "$(awk '/SwapTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo).swap"
```

If you need the `SwapTotal` line in the file:

```
rm -f *.swap
swap="$(awk '/SwapTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo)"
grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo > "${swap}.swap"
```

or in one command (thanks to [Archemar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/79818/archemar) for the hint):

```
rm -f *.swap
awk '/SwapTotal/ { print $0 > $2 ".swap" ;}' /proc/meminfo
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something as simple as

`touch /path/to/file/$(cat /proc/meminfo | grep SwapTotal | awk '{print $2}').swap`

Comment: `cat | grep | awk` is unnecessary. AWK can do all of that. See Stephen Kitt's first and last examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this :

```
touch `awk '/SwapTotal/ { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo`.swap
```